# Concatenate document.location.origin in the url of image

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to concatenate `document.location.origin` in the url of an image as per the code below. I already tried it in several ways and I can not hit the syntax anyone could help me.

I need to pass on the src: `src= document.location.origin/sin/img/blue.jpg`

This is a leaflet map with layerGroup where each one has an image next, I need to pass the url of the image dynamically so I do not have to swap in src when it's on localhost or on the production server

```
var mbAttr = '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetmapConsultaView</a>',
        mbUrl =  'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osm   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {attribution: mbAttr}),
        smf  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {attribution: mbAttr});

    var mapConsultaView = L.map('mapConsultaView', {
        center: [-30.038037, -51.199163],
        zoom: 14,
        layer:[osm]
    });

    var baseLayers = {
        "OSM": osm,
        "SMF": smf
    };
var overlaymap = {
            "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/blue.jpg' width:'27' height:'12'> Projetados": projetadoLayer,
            "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/green.jpg' width:'27' height:'12' > Instalado": instaladoLayer,
            "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/grey.jpg' width:'27' height:'12' > Retirado": retiradoLayer,
            "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/red.jpg' width:'27' height:'12' > Desativado": desativadoLayer,
            "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/black.jpg' width:'27' height:'12'> Cancelado": canceladoLayer

    };



    //var sinalizacoesLayer = L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(mapConsultaView); 
    L.control.layers(baseLayers,overlaymap,{collapsed:false}).addTo(mapConsultaView);
    baseLayers["OSM"].addTo(mapConsultaView);
```

Comment: `<img src='/sin/img/blue.jpg'>`

Answer (score 1):

`var src = document.location.origin + '/sin/img/blue.jpg'`

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your Object to a String and find all the occurrences and change them with the **str** javaScript function or you can loop through your object and change them one by one.

```js
var overlaymap = {
                "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/blue.jpg' width:'27' height:'12'> Projetados": "projetadoLayer",
                "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/green.jpg' width:'27' height:'12' > Instalado":"instaladoLayer",
                "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/grey.jpg' width:'27' height:'12' > Retirado":"retiradoLayer",
                "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/red.jpg' width:'27' height:'12' > Desativado":"desativadoLayer",
                "<img src='http://localhost:8080/sin/img/black.jpg' width:'27' height:'12'> Cancelado": "canceladoLayer"

};

function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

var stringOverlaymap = JSON.stringify(overlaymap);


stringOverlaymap = replaceAll(stringOverlaymap, "http://localhost:8080", "document.location.origin");



overlaymap = JSON.parse(stringOverlaymap);


console.log(overlaymap);
```

Comment: should be `replaceAll(stringOverlaymap, "http://localhost:8080", document.location.origin)` without the quotes around the replacement.